# Не типичная валидация url в laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, url, валидация

У меня есть поле в которое вписывается **url** я знаю что проверить правильность можно с помощью `'domain' => 'required|url'`
Только вот оно мне не подходит, потому что принимает за правильный только такие адресса `http://test.com` или `http://www.test.com` , а мне нужно чтобы валидировало так:
`http://test.com` - не прошло валидацию;
`http://www.test.com` - не прошло валидацию;
`www.test.com` - не прошло валидацию;
**test.com - прошло валидацию**;
как это правильно реализовать? Использовать regex:pattern ?

Answer (score 0):

Такие валидации нужно выполнять с помощью **regex**

Подробнее об этом в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation)

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так можно

```
'domain' => ['required', 'regex:/^((?:https?\:\/\/|www\.)(?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)*[-a-z0-9]+.*)$/']
```

Comment: Вроде как регулярка верна, а вот в ларавельке не проходит.

Comment: Потому что это регулярка на соответствие этому: `http://test.com` или `http://www.test.com`.

Comment: Рустам Гимранов, всё пропускает как угодно :) походу в конструкции 'url'   => ['regex' => ошибка или где то еще

Comment: regex сменил на not_regex тоже самое

Comment: Так то да, должно быть как минимум: `'domain' => ['required', 'regex:...']`

Comment: Рустам Гимранов, 'url'   => ['regex' => ... так тоже можно

Comment: InDevX, полазил в логах вот такую ошибку выдает preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found

Comment: Мой косяк. Неправильно валидацию вашу понял.. Исправил. @РустамГимранов правильно написал, но и с вложенностью можно, хотя в данном случае так делать нет необходимости

Answer (score 0):

```
    'domain' => [
        'required',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if (filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === $value) {
                $fail("$attribute must be without http:// and https://");
            } elseif (explode('.', $value)[0] === 'www') {
                $fail("$attribute must be without www");
            }
        },
    ]
```